# How to store HTML string in JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json, redis

I am using tinyMCE editor in my registration form.I print table in editor and submit form.I am storing this data in Redis in json format.But while I fetch json and decode it, json is not decoded properly due to html string.So I have did google and find to solution to addslashes near quatition.I did that also now problem is for whitespaces.If i remove whitespaces and decode it.it is decoded properly.I want to know proper solution of it.

Here is my problematic json string

```
{"Body":"<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" style=\"width:500px\"><tbody><tr>  <td>{-REMITTANCE_BATCH-}</td>   <td>Remittance Batch</td></tr><tr>  <td>{-REMITTANCE_BATCH-}</td>   <td>Remittance Batch</td></tr><tr>  <td>{-REMITTANCE_BATCH-}</td>   <td>Remittance Batch</td></tr></tbody></table><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>"}
```

[image]

Comment: fetch json only and build html in javascript via jquery after receiving json response

Comment: save json in hidden input field and build html in javascript when required

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that json and it decodes fine. You should post the code that is giving you problems and explain what the problem is exactly.

Comment: Hello @jeroen While I post this json in stackoverflow it omit whitespces.Thats why it decode properly.see image I have added

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do that in a json, this is not the idea of using json. Transports only data and then in the same web via jquery built the html

Comment: While i fetch data from redis it is not loaded due to invalid json

Comment: what are you trying to do? post an example.